# Creating an appoint record for health professionals

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that allows a health professional(doctor,nurse etc) to create an appointment book to store patient appointment for each individual health professonal

here's my health professional class

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
* Write a description of class doctor here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class doctor
{
  // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
  private String name;
  private String profession;
  private String office;
 
  LocalDate date;
  LocalTime time;
  
  /**
   * Constructor for objects of class doctor
   */
  public doctor(String name,String profession,String office)
  {
      // initialise instance variables
      this.name=name;
      this.profession=profession;
      this.office=office;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
      return name;
  }

  public String getProfession()
  {
      return profession;
  }

  public String getOffice()
  {
      return office;
  }

  /**
   * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
   *
   * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
   * @return    the sum of x and y
   */
  public String printInfo()
  {
      String info;

      info = "name: " + name +"; profession: "+profession + "; office: "+office;

      return info;
  }
}
```

here's the appointment class

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

/**
 * Performs actions on the list's nodes
 *
 * @author AC12001 Team
 * @version January 2018
 */
public class record
{
    // instance variables
    private String treatment;
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime endTime;
    private LocalTime startTime;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class List
     */
    public record(String treatment,LocalDate date,LocalTime endTime,LocalTime startTime)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.treatment = treatment;
        this.date=date;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.startTime=startTime;

    }

    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Get the student ID
     *
     * @return student at this node
     */
    public String getTreatment()
    {
        return treatment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mark
     *
     * @return mark at this node
     */
    public LocalTime getEndTime()
    {
        return endTime;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * Return a string containing the data from this node, formatted
     */
    public String printInfo()
    {
        String info;

        info = "Treatement Type:  " + treatment +"start time:  "+startTime + "end time :"+endTime;

        return info;
    }
}
```

I created an arrayList that stores an object of the doctor class
`ArrayList<doctor> hold=new ArrayList();`
but i want each doctor object to be able to create appointments, i'm stumped on how to go about this

Comment: Make a `reserveAppointment()` method on `Doctor` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```java
class Doctor {
    // Create a property inside the Doctor class with their appointments 
    final ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...

    // Create a method to add an appointment
    // You must also define a signature to it, such as
    // 1: #addRecord(Record)
    // 2: #addRecord(String, LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalTime)
    //
    // Below I'll be using 2
    boolean addRecord(String treatment, LocalDate date, LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
        // Create a new appointment
        final Record record = new Record(treatment, date, end, start);
      
        // Add it to the doctor appointments
        return records.add(record);
    } 

    // Create a getter for all the records created by this doctor
    List<Record> getRecords() {
        // Don't allow anyone but the doctor to modify it
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(records);
    }
}
```

---

> if I wanted to print the record using the printInfo in records how will I do it

You can return a `Record` in your `addRecord` method with the recently added record.

```java
Record addRecord(String treatment, LocalDate date, LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
    final Record record = new Record(treatment, date, end, start);
    records.add(record);
    return record;
}
```

> if I want to do normal ArrayList operations like delete,edit do I have to do it in the doctor class

That's up to your implementation. If you want to do in your doctor class, just add some more methods to update and remove. If you want to do it outside, just change your `getRecords` method:

```java
List<Record> getRecords() {
    // Allow anyone to modify it
    return records;
}
```

Comment: the return Collections.unmodifiableList(records) is showing an error

Comment: You must add a `import java.util.Collections;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Just realised my mistake i changed List<Record> getRecords() to ArrayList<record> getRecords(), but the  List<Record> getRecords() is showing an error List does not take parameters

Comment: Can you share the full `getRecords` method? You can edit in your question.

Comment: no need fixed it, forgot to import java.util.List;  but I was wondering if I wanted to print the record using the printInfo in records how will I do it, since the addRecords is a boolean an not a record object. Also if I want to do normal ArrayList operations like delete,edit do I have to do it in the doctor class